# Convert python code with sha to php

Tags: php, python, hash, sha, digest

got a problem with converting python to php. I've got the following code in python:

```
user = "DdrkmK5uFKmaaeNqfqReMADSUJ4sVSLrV2A8Bvs8"
passing = "K9hvwANSBW5tLYzuWptWMByTtzZZKHzm"

sha = hashlib.sha256()
sha.update(user)
sha.update(passing)
sha_A = [ord(x) for x in sha.digest()]
```

`sha_A` is the following array:

[231, 13, 239, 136, 20, 198, 76, 121, 67, 163, 251, 153, 114, 13, 65, 203, 41, 37, 64, 168, 43, 69, 81, 103, 235, 161, 15, 58, 82, 57, 217, 178]

---

I already converted it to php:

```
$user = "DdrkmK5uFKmaaeNqfqReMADSUJ4sVSLrV2A8Bvs8";
$passing = "K9hvwANSBW5tLYzuWptWMByTtzZZKHzm"

$sha = hash_init("sha256");
$sha = hash_update($sha, $user);
$sha = hash_update($sha, $passing);

$sha_A = [];
$i = 0;
$digest = openssl_digest($sha, "sha256");
$digest = str_split($digest);
foreach ($digest as $x) {
  $sha_A[$i] = ord($x);
  $i = $i + 1;
}
```

But the returned array `$sha` looks like this one:

[101, 51, 98, 48, 99, 52, 52, 50, 57, 56, 102, 99, 49, 99, 49, 52, 57, 97, 102, 98, 102, 52, 99, 56, 57, 57, 54, 102, 98, 57, 50, 52]

Maybe some of you will find my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw few errors in your PHP code.

This is a python snippet:

```
>>> sha = hashlib.sha256()
>>> sha.update(user)
>>> sha.update(passing)
>>> sha_A = [ord(x) for x in sha.digest()]
[135, 146, 107, 215, 70, 126, 179, 21, 19, 177, 191, 236, 182, 136, 192, 53, 148, 42, 160, 24, 63, 224, 170, 211, 32, 131, 59, 146, 60, 162, 77, 2]
```

And the PHP version, corrected:

```
$ctx = hash_init('sha256');
hash_update($ctx, $user);
hash_update($ctx, $passing);
$digest = hash_final($ctx, true);

$sha_A = [];
foreach (str_split($digest) as $x) {
    $sha_A[] = ord($x);
}
[135, 146, 107, 215, 70, 126, 179, 21, 19, 177, 191, 236, 182, 136, 192, 53, 148, 42, 160, 24, 63, 224, 170, 211, 32, 131, 59, 146, 60, 162, 77, 2]
```

In your PHP version, `$sha = hash_update($sha, $user);` was bad because [hash_update](https://secure.php.net/manual/function.hash-update.php) returns a boolean. The first argument is called the `context` and is the result of [hash_init](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-init.php), the second one is the data to hash. Finally, you call [hash_final](https://secure.php.net/manual/function.hash-final.php) with the last parameter (`raw_output`) to `true` to get binary data.

Last error, using `openssl_digest` on the SHA result's was computing the digest of the SHA digest's. Funny, isn't it? :).

Comment: Thank you. That's helping me :) But what's with the following part:  sha_A = [ord(x) for x in sha.digest()]   Did i convert it correctly?